# Civizualize does not render

Tags: civisualize

Using Civicrm 4.6.5 and the latest master branch of Civizualize at github https://github.com/TechToThePeople/civisualize,
The page /civicrm/dataviz shows the default visualizations list, but when I click on one of them, the vizualization does not render.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/d3.v3.js?nsuhjj:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/dc/crossfilter.js?nsuhjj:1

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/dc/dc.js?nsuhjj:1

```
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/dataviz/contribute:323

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a javascript error.

Most likely it's that you didn't properly configure the extension url for your extension. What configuration do you have?

Checkout your browser console, do you have any error message? something about d3 missing?

You can also look at your Developer Tools (press F12 in Firefox/Chrome), and check the "Network" tab.  Are you seeing 404 errors?  Look at the URL that's getting a 404 error.  Is there actually a file in that location?  It's very possible that your "Extensions URL" is incorrect.  Go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs** and change the Extension Resource URL to match the actual location of your extensions.

Comment: Regarding the extension url...to me it looks good (see additional screenshots above)

Comment: and is this the url of the path where you put extensions and accessible from the web? Do you have any javascript error message?

Comment: Yes, see additional screenshots above.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/d3.v3.js?nsuhjj:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/dc/crossfilter.js?nsuhjj:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/civisualize-master/js/dc/dc.js?nsuhjj:1

ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
http://crm.conscious.life/civicrm/dataviz/contribute:323

Comment: This means that the system is not able to load d3.js. If you can send us your js consol logs, that would help.

Comment: I see in the Chrome javascript concole the same what I already posted above (see screenshots) ReferenceError: d3 is not defined.

Comment: @yuri, you have a lot of errors before that one. these are the root cause of your problem. are you sure the js loaded are really js and not html error messages - that would indicate a nginx or apache rewrite rule error

Comment: @Xavier what you ask is beyond my skills. I'm not a programmer, just site builder. I could give access to the site if the developers would like to know why it doesn't work...or I can assist if someone assist me step by step to investige it. This is a civicrm installation with a standard lamp stack.

Comment: @Yuri I just experienced the same issue.  I've just updated this answer to be a little clearer and site builder-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but a different console error:

mailings:361 Uncaught TypeError: data.values.forEach is not a function(anonymous function) @ mailings:361

Comment: Ah. Data set is too big? I forced down the number of records being selected and even at 8,200 I get this script error:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. The console output is as follows (For those troubleshooting along at home, reach the console in Chrome by hitting Shift+Ctrl+I and choosing the console tab):

[image]

The uncaught error seems to refer to the line that says `var numberFormat = d3.format(".2f");` in civicrm/dataviz/contribute found on line 48 of Contribute.tpl.

But I'm not sure how to proceed. If it's relevant, I'm running 4.7.14 on Drupal 7.53 on CentOS 6.8.